# Replacing gui interaction to enable automation

Tags: swt, jython

I'm trying to add automation to a GUI programme that collates test data from a rhapsody model. The author made it so that you had to load in secondary files manually and manually save it. I have managed to automate these steps. However there is a button with the following definition;

```
def btnCopySummaryClicked(self,event):
  text""
  for label in [self.lblReadyForRegression, self.lblNotReady,
        self.lblMissingParent]:
     text += label.getText() + "\n"
  self.copyToClipboard(text)
```

My question is how do I replicate this in a standalone function that I can call, rather than having it wait for a button to be pressed.

Side note - I don't understand how the function works, just that it copys the relevant info so the user can paste it somewhere else. I'd like to print the info straight to a file.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't think this question has anything to do with [SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/)...

Comment: The programme uses the swt module. I wasn't sure if this would make a difference if people thought I was using the tinker(?) module so I though I should include it

Comment: ah ok, ill remove it

Comment: my mistake, turns out the programme is in jython and is using Java SWT